# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. Invalid keystore format

Tags: flutter, apk, build

Soy un poco nuevo en flutter y al querer generar una apk con "Flutter build apk" me sale el siguiente error:

```
Execution failed for task 'app: packageRelease'.
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key test from store "C: \ path \ key.properties": Invalid keystore format
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola Dani, bienvenido a SOes, traduce tu pregunta al español para que pueda ser respondida, si no acabarán cerrándola.

Comment: `flutter build` te genera la app en modo release. Necesitas un signin key y poner la info en el build.gradle.

Comment: Si, se necesita una key, esa la genero a partir de los datos que encuentro en un archivo llamado key properties, pero igual me sale ese error, el proyecto lo estaba dirigiendo otra persona, pero la key se genera a partir del  key properties verdad?